# why , the position of setContentView() is creating Error

Tags: android

why , this is NOT-OK , it is creating errors .

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

btn = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_according_to_book);
```

and if i am putting "**setContentView(R.layout.activity_according_to_book);**" at Second line just after "**super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);**" , it is not creating Errors .

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_according_to_book);

btn = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: What errors? Would you mind sharing them?

Comment: without setting the content layout , btn.setOnClickListener(this) will produce null pointer exception as findViewById(R.id.button) will be null... as NO layout has been set... keep setContentview on top .. whats the issue..

Answer (score 0):

By calling `setContentView()` you're inflating the view hierarchy for your `Activity`, then you're getting references to the `Views` by calling `findViewById()`. If you did not call `setContentView()` - you don't have any `Views` in the view hierarchy, so you can't reference them. Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It creates error because the app loads the layout after calling `setContentView`, so `findViewById` before that method will always return null.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling

```
      findViewById(R.id.button);
```

the Button is searched on R.layout.activity_according_to_book .

So setContentView(R.layout.activity_according_to_book);

has to be before you are looking for views.